# How to switch to LDAP users in shell script and perform events on NFS mount?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ldap, nfs

I'm quite new to shell scripting.I have a shell script which has Userslist as Array. User is randomly picked and readwrite operations are performed.

```
declare -a userNameslist=('user1' 'user2' 'user3' 'user4')
function readAndWriteandDelete{
mount a nfs volume 
switch as user 1 
perform readfiles [as user1]
perform writefiles [as user1]
perform deletefiles [as user1]
}
```

I tried **su -c "touch abc.log" -m user1** but using this only touch command is performed as user1. remaining commands are executed as root user .Please let me know how to perform all events as single user.Any help/pointers would be helpful

Comment: That array syntax is not a valid to bash...

Comment: To check bash syntax, you can use https://www.shellcheck.net/.  For sudo, it will only perform the single command you put after the `-c` argument.  Therefore, each command in your script requires a `sudo` in front.  OR, run the entire script with sudo.  i.e. put all your commands in script.bash, and run it with `sudo script.bash`.

Comment: @Jetchisel , Thanks , I have updated the array as in code